# unread-command-events and batch mode

Tags: interactive, testing, events

I'm writing tests for an interactive function. I've been using the `unread-command-events` variable in conjunction with `call-interactively` to verify that it does the right thing.

However, I just discovered that this doesn't work in batch mode.

For example:

```
(defun my-dummy (s)
  (interactive "sWrite something: ")
  s)

(ert-deftest my-dummy-test ()
  (let ((unread-command-events (listify-key-sequence "Hi!\n")))
    (should (equal (call-interactively #'my-dummy)
                   "Hi!"))))
```

When running `ert` in interactive mode, this works. However, in batch mode, Emacs stops and read the keyboard without consuming input from `unread-command-events`.

In this a bug in batch mode or is this the expected behaviour?

Is there any other way to do this in batch mode?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, but you can circumvent this problem by let-binding `executing-kbd-macro` to `t`, which will convince the minibuffer commands to read from `unread-command-events` rather than from stdin.

Comment: Can you elaborate why this is the expected behavior. Binding a somewhat unrelated variable `executing-kbd-macro` sounds like a hack in my eyes. At the very minimum, this should be documented in relevant places, e.g. in the documentation of `unread-command-events`.

Comment: @Lindydancer: Agreed, it's a hack.  I found out how to do it by reading the C code; I don't think it was designed for what you need, it just happens to do the trick.  `M-x report-emacs-bug` might be in order to request either better doc, or some less hacky solution.